# referencing the html object that made the ExternalInterface.call to the javascript function called

Tags: javascript, object, actionscript, reference, externalinterface

i apologize if my terminology is off, my actionscript skills are pretty weak sauce.

so, i have some actionscript that makes a

ExternalInterface.call('someFunction');

call.

is it possible to reference the html object that made the call to someFunction directly using the ExternalInterface.call call?

Assume that the object that makes the call also has some Callbacks (via ExternalInterface.addCallback) that are accessible via javascript.

Currently:

```
Actionscript source

ExternalInterface.call("someFunction");
ExternalInterface.addCallback("someCallback",someASfunction);

Javascript source

function someFunction(){
    document.getElementById('idOfSWFObject').someCallback();
}
```

I'm thinking there must be a way of:

```
Actionscript source

ExternalInterface.call("someFunction",THE_OBJECT_MAKING_THE_CALL);
ExternalInterface.addCallback("someCallback",someASfunction);

Javascript source

function someFunction(o){
    o.someCallback();
}
```

once again, sorry about the terminology. tried to lace it with as many keywords for future searches.

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are talking about ExternalInterface.objectID. This property returns an id associated with flash container in *object* or *embed* tag.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.en#objectID

I suggest that you should also pass the name of "someCallback" to you JS method. This way there will be no need to hardcode it in JS.

Here's an example

```
// Actionscript source

const jsMethodName:String = "someFunction";
const asCallbackName:String = "someCallback";
ExternalInterface.call(jsMethodName+"(document.getElementById("++")"++");");
ExternalInterface.addCallback(asCallbackName,someASfunction);

// Javascript source

function someFunction(flashId, callbackName) 
{
    var flashContainer = document.getElementById(flashId);
    flashContainer["callbackName"]();
}
```

**EDIT:** If you really want to get a reference to flash DOM object in someFunction arguments, you may achieve it in a bit tricky way (I would rather not, but just for your interest).

```
// Actionscript source

const jsMethodName:String = "someFunction";
const asCallbackName:String = "someCallback";
ExternalInterface.addCallback(asCallbackName,someASfunction);

ExternalInterface.call(
    "function(){"+ 
        jsMethodName+"("+
            "document.getElementById('"+ExternalInterface.objectID+"'),"+
            "'"+asCallbackName+"'"+
        ");"+
    "}"
);    

// Javascript source

function someFunction(flashContainer, callbackName) 
{
    flashContainer[callbackName]();
}
```

This way you inject some JS code from flash into js. It works, but looks messy.

Comment: close to what i was looking for, but i was hoping more like passing a reference to the actual object itself not a string of the id name. its quite possible that what i'm looking for isnt possible ;)

Comment: Well, as far as i know, it's definitely not possible. Everything you pass through arguments of ExternalInterface call gets serialized, hence you can not obtain a reference in the process. However, you can do the trick: first argument of EI call is evalueted in JS, and what you can place there is more then just a method name. :) See my edit in the answer above.