# Return value to Flash from Javascript

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to test in Flash if the DIV it is in has been expanded or not.

In the JavaScript I have :

```
  function isExpanded() {
     return this.expanded;
  }
```

In the actionscript I have :

```
var isExp = ExternalInterface.call('isExpanded');
ExternalInterface.call('console.log', 'isExpanded is '+isExp);
```

When I test the JavaScript it returns the correct value, but the ActionScript returns undefined.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the JS function like so:

```
function isExpanded() {
    return this.expanded;
}
```

And depending on the type of value `isExpanded()` returns, your AS should define `isExp`'s type. For example:

`var isExp:Boolean`

I suggest also looking at the answer in this question to properly reference the object you intend to get with `this`:
[referencing the html object that made the ExternalInterface.call to the javascript function called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504369/referencing-the-html-object-that-made-the-externalinterface-call-to-the-javascri)

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a typo.  I'll fix the original question to reflect the proper formatting.

Comment: What is `this` referencing? Are you sure the `expanded` property exists?